# Jquery 'change' event cancel 'click' event on other element

Tags: jquery, events

I write this sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:text').change(inputChangeHandler);
        $('input:button').click(buttonClickHandler);
    });
    function inputChangeHandler(event){
        alert('[Text changed] ' + $(this).val());
    }
    function buttonClickHandler(event){
        alert('[Button click]');
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="txt" />
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

Try to change text, then click on button, only 'change event' is triggered.

Any idea to trigger the event of 'change' that the 'click'?

Answer (score 2):

Probably alert is stopping the second event, if I change your code to log messages in console, in Firefox both events are triggered.

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('input:text').change(inputChangeHandler); 
        $('input:button').click(buttonClickHandler); 
    }); 
    function inputChangeHandler(event){ 
        console.log('[Text changed] ' + $(this).val()); 
    } 
    function buttonClickHandler(event){ 
        console.log('[Button click]'); 
    } 
</script> 

<input type="text" name="txt" /> 
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

Comment: work! now I have to understand why my code don't work with 2 ajax calls (instead of console.log).

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/49HQM/) fiddle.

Comment: I try this with my browser (chrome 15) and not work, try to write 'help' on textbox, then press on button... i see only one dialog box (text change event), not second dialog (button click)

Comment: That is because two alerts are firing at the same time. If you perform the two events separately it will not happen. For example, type in the textbox, then blur (but do not click the button), then click the button.

Comment: On real case i am 2 differents ajax calls, one on each handler, but only one is fired! (input changed, not button pressed).